# asp.net core 3.1: not all class members bind to Json in post method

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc

Im at a loss. I spent a day on this... and I miss what Im doing wrong.
working with asp.net core 3.1, doing a POST method:

here is my POCO:

```
public class SupplierSchedule
{
        public int scheduleId { get; set; } //not sure if will ever be used
        public int supplierId { get; set; }
        public byte scheduleType { get; set; }
        public string gadolEd { get; set; }
}
```

my method:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult<SupplierSchedule>> Post([FromBody]SupplierSchedule [] supplierSchedules)
{
....
```

My Json:

```
[{
"supplierId":"7",
"scheduleId":7,
"scheduleType":"4",
"gadolEd": "4"
}]
```

Now originally, I had 2 members: just the supplierId and ScheduleId. those bind nicely to the Json. all good. but I added those 2 other fields (scheduleType, gadolEd) and those just dont bind to the Json in the HTTP POST body

any idea why!? what on earth am I missing??

Thanks
Jonathan

Comment: Have you tried using `"scheduleType":4,` in your JSON (without the double quotes around the value)?

Comment: "added those 2 other fields (scheduleType, gadolEd) " Can you post the code you used to add ?

Comment: marc_c: Yes I did. I tried all possible combinations. quotes on and off (taht's not it because the first 2 fields do keep their binding even when i play with quotes)  tried to change types of those 2 other fields as well... nothing. they just don't bind

Comment: Serge:  simply added them. what do you mean what code I used?

Answer (score 0):

It is my turn to apologize for this post. Turns out there was an intermediary service between my caller and the service in question that filtered out parts of the Json. My bad

Comment: Answers (and questions) should be written such that future users can learn from them, too. Please either [edit] this answer to provide details about what was wrong, or consider deleting your question entirely (I think you'll have to delete this answer first).